# Pyspark - Difference between 2 dataframes - Identify inserts, updates and deletes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes df1(old) and df2(new). I am trying compare df2 with df1 and find the newly added rows, deleted rows, updated rows along with the names of the columns that got updated.

Here is the code that I have written

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, when, array_remove, lit

data1 = [("James","rob","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","jim","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","dunkin","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","60563","F",-1)
  ]

data2 = [("James","rob","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Robert","dunkin","Williams","42114","M",2000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","72712","F",3000),
    ("Yesh","Reddy","Brown","75234","M",3000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","60563","F",-1)
  ]
  schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
conditions_ = [when(df1[c]!=df2[c], lit(c)).otherwise("") for c in df1.columns if c not in ['firstname','middlename','lastname']]

select_expr =[
                col("firstname"),col("middlename"),col("lastname"),
                *[df2[c] for c in df2.columns if c not in ['firstname','middlename','lastname']], 
                array_remove(array(*conditions_), "").alias("updated_columns")
]

df1.join(df2, ["firstname","middlename","lastname"],"inner").select(*select_expr).show()
```

Here is the output that I got

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|updated_columns|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+
|    James|       rob|   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|             []|
|   Robert|    dunkin|Williams|42114|     M|  2000|       [salary]|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|72712|     F|  3000|   [id, salary]|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|60563|     F|    -1|             []|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+
```

Here is the output that I am expecting

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+-----------------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|updated_columns|           status|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+-----------------+
|    James|       rob|   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|             []|        unchanged|
|   Robert|    dunkin|Williams|42114|     M|  2000|       [salary]|          updated|
|  Michael|      Rose|     jim|40288|     M|  4000|             []|          deleted|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|72712|     F|  3000|   [id, salary]|          updated|
|     Yesh|     Reddy|   Brown|75234|     M|  3000|             []|            added|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|60563|     F|    -1|             []|        unchanged|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I know that I can find the added and deleted rows using the left anti joins separately. But, I am looking for ways to update my existing join to get the above output.

Comment: You probably want to look at using dr1.subtract(dr2) it will give you the diff.  I'm sure from there what you want is within reach.  You could user hdfs/ranger audit logs to also tease out this information. Just to give you another option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [`outer join`](https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/sql-join-types-explained-visually/) would help in your case. I have modified the code you have given to do this and also include the status column.

### Minimally Working Example

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, when, array_remove, lit, size, coalesce
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data1 = [("James","rob","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","jim","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","dunkin","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","60563","F",-1)
  ]

data2 = [("James","rob","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Robert","dunkin","Williams","42114","M",2000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","72712","F",3000),
    ("Yesh","Reddy","Brown","75234","M",3000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","60563","F",-1)
  ]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True),
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True),
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)
  ])
 
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
conditions_ = [when(df1[c]!=df2[c], lit(c)).otherwise("") for c in df1.columns if c not in ['firstname','middlename','lastname']]
```

Logic for `status` Column and modified `select_expr` to `coalesce` values from `df2` and `df1` with preference given to `df2` to get the update to date data.

```
status = when(df1["id"].isNull(), lit("added")).when(df2["id"].isNull(), lit("deleted")).when(size(array_remove(array(*conditions_), "")) > 0, lit("updated")).otherwise("unchanged")

select_expr =[
                col("firstname"),col("middlename"),col("lastname"),
                *[coalesce(df2[c], df1[c]).alias(c) for c in df2.columns if c not in ['firstname','middlename','lastname']],                
                array_remove(array(*conditions_), "").alias("updated_columns"),
                status.alias("status"),
]
```

Finally, applying an `outer join`.

```
df1.join(df2, ["firstname","middlename","lastname"],"outer").select(*select_expr).show()
```

### Output

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+---------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|updated_columns|   status|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+---------+
|    James|       rob|   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|             []|unchanged|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|60563|     F|    -1|             []|unchanged|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|72712|     F|  3000|   [id, salary]|  updated|
|  Michael|      Rose|     jim|40288|     M|  4000|             []|  deleted|
|   Robert|    dunkin|Williams|42114|     M|  2000|       [salary]|  updated|
|     Yesh|     Reddy|   Brown|75234|     M|  3000|             []|    added|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the status with out using the column "id"?

Comment: @yAsH you can use a combined condition that uses the column used in the join condition. So the condition would be, `when(df1["firstname"].isNull() & df1["middlename"].isNull() & df1["lastname"].isNull(), lit("added"))` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Ranger so you capture what actually changes, and when.  But if you only have theses data frames...
You want to do a "outer" join. (pulls all data from both tables into one join.)  You already have the update column logic.

For Status: "deleted"(In df1 but not df2) and "additions"(in df2, but not in df1), (if there are update columns) --> "updated" otherwise "unchanged".

Comment: what is Ranger  ?

Comment: Ranger is a security framework for Hadoop: https://ranger.apache.org/  It keeps track of who access what when.  
There are also other ways to tack who did what when by looking at spark logs, but ranger is a little cleaner.